# solution verification for events problems

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:
Let A, B and C are three arbitrary events. I have to use them to describe:

1. all 3 of the events A, B and C have occurred
2. at least one of the events A, B, C has occurred
3. exactly one of the events A, B, C has occurred
4. not a single one of the events A, B, C has occurred
5. not more than 2 of the events A, B, C have occurred

My solution:

1. $A \cap B \cap C$
2. $A \cup B \cup C$
3. $(A \setminus(B \cup C)) \cup (B \setminus(A \cup C)) \cup (C \setminus(A \cup B))$
4. $\bar A\cap \bar B\cap \bar C$
5. $((A\cup B)\cap \bar C) \cup ((A\cup C)\cap \bar B) \cup ((B\cup C)\cap \bar A)$

Is this correct and if yes are there simpler ways on describing the desired events?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all: events are *fixed* measurable subsets of some sample space $\Omega$. In this context it is better to call them "arbitrary" instead "random" and also a recommendation to mention that they are distinct (If $A=B=C$ then how to answer 3?) .1) correct. 2) correct. I have critics on the questions 3,4,5: they miss a reference to $A,B,C$. In e.g. 3) "exactly one event" must be changed into "exactly one of *the* events". (event $\Omega$ always occurs so without such reference how to answer 4?). Sortlike for 4) and 5).

Comment: @drhab Thank you! I've added an edit. It was actually arbitrary in the text, but I have translated it in a wrong way to random. I have edited the questions so that they are more concrete.

Comment: Preassuming that the events are distinct all answers are correct.